# changing some element and also input from the same file without deleting

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, terminal, prompt

in a for loop i want to change a file again and again and also saved it in the same file without delete how can i do that?

```
    function change() {
  for i in {0..28}
  do
    echo ",${cryp_data_letter[$i]}" "${org_data[$i]}"
    sed "s/,${cryp_data_letter[$i]}/${org_data[$i]}/g" < "./dummy.txt" > "./dummy.txt"  # this line 
                                                                      # always delete the entire 
                                                                         #file content
    cat "./dummy.txt"
  done
}
```

For example our file first has :

```
,A,B,C,D,E,F
```

first change:

```
XYCDEF
```

we should save the last changes and also receive it as an input again after second change the file should contain "XYCDEF"

NOTE:I don't want to append new content to a file i want to rewrite

Comment: Did you try the `-i` option like `sed -i "s/,${cryp_data_letter[$i]}/${org_data[$i]}/g" "./dummy.txt"`

Comment: Or without loop `tr "AB" "XY" < dummy.txt` ?

Comment: `s/,${cr` - you match a `,` comma before the letter. This does not match the example you provided, is this ok?

Comment: @KamilCuk sorry i just fixed. Do you have any idea?

Comment: still deleted the content @WalterA

Comment: `still deleted the content` substitute the line `sed "s/,${cryp_data_letter[$i]}/${org_data[$i]}/g" < "./dummy.txt" > "./dummy.txt"` for `sed -i "s/,${cryp_data_letter[$i]}/${org_data[$i]}/g" "./dummy.txt"` and it should work.

Comment: Content is deleted when you write (redirect `>`) to the same file you are reading from (`<`).  This can be avoided with `sed` option `-i` (without redirection like my first comment) or by using a temp file (`tr "AB" "XY" < dummy.txt > tempfile && mv tempfile dummy.txt`)

Comment: Did you try to use another way round e.g. cat dummy.txt | sed 's/XXX/YYY/g' > dummy.txt ?

Comment: it solved my problem thanks for the answer. But in some case it is not be changed. For example ==> ",z,e,r" after the process this should be "kel" but it return ",er" is it a language problem or i have missed something again? Do you have any idea for that? If you want to see whole code i can send it. @KamilCuk

Comment: And also how can i modify the line for unicode ? @KamilCuk

Comment: That is the problem with insufficient testdata. The original question is answered.
We can't see what is happening, maybe `z` is changed into `k` and `k` is changed into `,`. Perhaps try `tr ${cryp_data_letter[$i]}" "${org_data[$i]}" < dummy.txt`